# Substitute color with patterns (stripes, lines) in bar ggplot - clustered data

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, ggpattern

I am trying to do a bar plot for grouped data, where each group has a pattern. Colors look rather ugly so I have tried substituting it with a pattern.

My data looks like this :

```
Time <- c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,  6,  6,  6, 11, 11 ,11, 11, 11)
 Group <- c("A",  "B", "C","D","E","A","B","C" ,"D","E","A","B","C","D","E","A","B","C","D","E","A", "B","C","D","E", "A","B","C","D","E") 
 Values <- c(38.4161807,  1.8280313, 34.1550423,  0.0000000, 37.2460332, 66.4168001 ,59.3746830 , 2.9191253,  5.6341807 , 3.5369600, 84.2639108, 11.1884641, 0.0000000 ,73.0754466  ,0.0000000, 60.5906227, 42.6958082  ,2.2462260 ,14.6034461,  1.4389593  ,2.2875870  ,1.4289716  ,0.0000000,  0.0000000, 0.8586154,  4.7177827 , 1.7227924 , 2.9949903 , 0.0000000 , 0.0000000)
 data <- c(Time, Group, Values)
```

I have used this to make colors in the bars:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=as.factor(Time), y=Values, fill=Group )) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
scale_fill_manual(name="Group",
                      values=c("black", "Grey", "blue", "green", "yellow")) +
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

However, I want the bars filled by patterns like this for example:

[image]

I have tried ggpattern with both the pattern() and pattern_fill() functions but there are no changes at all.

Comment: I believe `geom_bar_pattern()` is from `ggpattern`, a ggplot2 addon.

Answer (score 0):

`geom_bar_pattern()` is what you are looking for which is in the `ggpattern` library

You will have to use `ggplot2` to use `ggpattern`. The pattern instead of color is only available with the `ggpattern` library

**EDIT**

I get the same output as yuliaUU when formulating a solution

```
data <- data.frame(Time, Group, Values)

library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)
ggplot(data,aes(Time,Values)) +
    geom_col_pattern(aes(fill=Group),colour='blue',pattern='stripe') +
    theme_bw() +
    labs(title='Time - Group - Value') +
    theme(legend.key.size=unit(1.5,'cm'))
```

[image]

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggpattern/vignettes/patterns-stripes.html

Comment: Is it only me or this ggpattern does not load properly? I have tried multiple times and the File window remains blank, while the console says that R in running. It seems almost like R has a problem rendering the plot from ggpattern

Answer (score 0):

```
        library(ggpattern)
ggplot(data, aes(Time, Values)) +
  geom_col_pattern(
    aes(pattern = Group, pattern_angle = Group, pattern_spacing = Group), 
    fill            = 'white',
    colour          = 'black', 
    pattern_density = 0.35, 
    pattern_fill    = 'black',
    pattern_colour  = 'black'
  ) +
  scale_pattern_spacing_discrete(range = c(0.01, 0.05))
```

[image]